# How can I view log events remotely using Log4J and Apache Chainsaw?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, apache-chainsaw

I have a Java web application that currently uses [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html) for logging.  I'd like to use [Apache Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html) to view and parse the logs remotely.  So far, I've had trouble understanding how to setup both the client side (the Chainsaw client) and the server side (the log4j config in my webapp) to successfully enable remote logging.

Here is what I have tried so far.

**Server side log4j config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true">

   <appender name="myRFA" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="/logs}/my.log"/>
      <param name="Append" value="false" />
      <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
      <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{ISO8601} %p - [%X{LoggingId}] - %t - %c - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <appender name="SOCKET" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender">
      <param name="Port" value="4445"/>
      <param name="RemoteHost" value="localhost"/>
      <param name="ReconnectionDelay" value="60000"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
   </appender>

   <logger name="com" additivity="false">
      <level value="warn"/>
      <appender-ref ref="myRFA"/>
   </logger>

   <logger name="org" additivity="false">
      <level value="warn"/>
      <appender-ref ref="myRFA"/>
   </logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

**Client side Chainsaw config**

I created a new receiver with the following properties

```
name=SOCKET
port=4445
```

I will admit that I don't really understand how it is all supposed to work.  Is Chainsaw polling the remote server?  Is the remote server connecting to Chainsaw and pushing events to it?

Guidance, links to simple tutorials, or alternate tools would all be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add your SOCKET appender to each logger:

```
   <logger name="com" additivity="false">
      <level value="warn"/>
      <appender-ref ref="myRFA"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SOCKET"/>
   </logger>

   <logger name="org" additivity="false">
      <level value="warn"/>
      <appender-ref ref="myRFA"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SOCKET"/>
   </logger>
```